# Moving rds data from one account to another account on the same region through vpc peering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, vpc

I need to move data from my rds' one table of one account to another account, in the same region using VPC peering. I know how to establish a vpc-peering but after that, I don't understand how routing table will help to move data specifically of a single table.

I don't want to move all of the data, just one table.

```
private static Connection dbConnFrom;
private static Connection dbConnTo;

static {
    try {
        dbConnFrom = DriverManager.getConnection("..address 1....");
        dbConnTo = DriverManager.getConnection("..address 2....");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting up a VPC peering for just this job may be the best use of technology and overhead you will have to plan for. For just one table, why not create an export of data from this table in S3 and load that into the target bucket i.e. another account?

Comment: what If I want to do that only for a couple of tables and not all? My aim is to have a docker container which is initialized and based on the arguments in the docker file it moves the data between tables or overwrites them.

Answer (score 0):

VPC peering is a solution which is meant for service to service communication and one such use case is data exchange. From what you have described so far, peering is something you should rule out for now and think on lines of building an export/sync utility (either batch or stream).